# How to do case insensitive search on dictionary key in CosmosDB?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I can't figure out a way to do a case insensitive search on dictionary keys in ComsosDB. My objects look like this:

```
...
"Codes": {
      "CodeSystem1": [
         "A1", "A2"
       ],
      "CodeSystem2": [
        "x1","x2"
     ]
},
...
```

Codes is a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

My query looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM c  WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Codes["CodeSystem2"], 'x1')`

However, I'd like to do a LOWER() on both the dictionary key and value, but it doesn't work like that.

`SELECT * FROM c  WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Codes[LOWER("CodeSystem2"]), LOWER('x1'))`

Any ideas? I can't change the structure of the objects, and rather not do the filtering in my .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

LOWER/UPPER will not work with Array elements as you would want. If you have something like this:

```
 "CodeSystem4": [
            "Z1"
        ],
        "CodeSystem5": "Z3"
```

We can use the lower with element CodeSystem5 as below:

```
select * from c where lower(c.Codes["CodeSystem5"]) = Lower('Z3')
```

But we cannot do the same with 'CodeSystem4' with ARRAY_CONTAINS, it will not return any result.

Also as per the below article, "*The LOWER system function does not utilize the index. If you plan to do frequent case insensitive comparisons, the LOWER system function may consume a significant amount of RU's. If this is the case, instead of using the LOWER system function to normalize data each time for comparisons, you can normalize the casing upon insertion.*"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-lower

One way is to add another searchable array in lower case to make it work through query. Or else we can filter it through the SDK